# C programming allocating space for a linked list type structure

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

Hi i am at the beginning of trying to implement some kind of list thing in C just to try and learn a little better. I have no code currently, just need some help with a hypothetical

```
#define MAX_LIST_SIZE 1024


typedef struct clist clist;

struct clist{
   
   clist *next;
   char  *data; 
 
}

void add_to_list(char *str, clist *current){
   //what code goes in here
   im guessing some sort of malloc adding the strlen of str plus the sizeof the clist
}

int main(){
   clist mylistofstrings;
}
```

if you can answer that, my next question is, is there a way of  changing the structure using a macro or something so you can add strings like the following

```
clist mystrings = ADDSTRING("add this");
ADDTOLIST(mystrings,"second string");
```

Comment: You'll need to allocate a node (`struct clist`), but there's no need to copy the string. You can just copy the pointer

Comment: can you give me an example of the code, if i want clist->data to point to a string, where do i allocate space for the string

Comment: I just said there's no need to allocate anything, that all you need to do is copy the pointer (`clist->data = str;`)

Comment: Sorry im very new to C so i realise this might be very basic for you. Can i keep just adding linked clists and adding new strings as far down as i want.  clist->data = str ,  clist->next->data = str , clist-next->next->data  = string

Comment: No, you will need to allocate those nodes. Again, already said that. And this isn't C specific. It's the same in every language.

Comment: hi sorry can you check my code, i got something to compile but it segfaults https://pastebin.com/DuxzjSsr i tried commenting out the ADD_STRING lines but still segfaults.

Comment: forget macros, use functions. There are numerous examples online that show how to create and use a linked list. SO isn't meant to be a tutorial or running debugging site. Make an attempt yourself. If you get stuck on a specific thing, post a [mre] _in the question_ (not an external link), and ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, you will have to note some points though:

If you are going to pass references to your linked list around:

1. You will need to allocate the structure for each node in the heap first. To avoid stack smashing.
2. You might even have to malloc your string, again to avoid stack smashing.
3. Then, you will have to link each node to each other.

If you are just doing it for fun, and you are not planning to pass references to your structure to different functions. Then you don't need to use malloc. Directly initialize them.